# jQuery animate breaks spacebar scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, jquery-animate

So spacebar scrolling is a typical, if not commonly used feature on browsers. I'm noticing that this functionality is broken when using jQuery to trigger scrolling (see embed on "Full Screen"). Anyone else encounter this issue? If so, how did you fix it?

```js
$('button').click(function () {
     $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(window).height()
    }, 600); 
});
```

```css
body {
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 600vh;
}

div {
  margin-top: 100vh;
  height: 50vh;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>click me to scroll!</button>
<div>scroll to this section</div>
```

Using Chrome 49.0.2623.112 on OSX and jQuery v2.1.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue you're seeing is a problem with `focus` on the button.  When the animate event fires, the page scrolls but the focus remains on the `click me to scroll` button.  When you press spacebar, it fires the button event again because it's still focused.

If you remove the button focus, scrolling with the spacebar seems to work correctly.

```
$('button').click(function () {
     $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(window).height()
    }, 600); 
    $(this).blur();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/CnEUh/3121/